# How do i stop google sheet from auto-calculation?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that will record delivery information. However one of the record we have right now have a barcode that start with equal (=) symbol(=00000-00). So whenever we fired our barcode reader at it. it return as 5 digits number (10000) with minus calculation instead of our office-use 7 digits number format. (10077-77)

From what i know, In excel you can turn auto-calculation off as simple as turning format into text for use manual setting for calculation. However that doesn't seems to be the case here for Google Sheet. Is there any workaround for this? I tried =right(B2, len(B2)-1) but all it does is removing first number out and ignore equal symbol entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best workaround is to treat it like a string:

[image]

You also have the option of displaying formulas:

[image]

Yet if you use a value of `=0000-00` or something with starting zeros, it will not display the zeros:

[image]

Comment: I already knew all these. But what i wanted is to make the process like this be automated. Because we have to scan the barcode, so anything we wrote beforehand will be overwritten. We also have a couple more formula in other column. So the 'Show Formulas' is really not the option.

Comment: How does the data go from the barcode scanner to the sheet? Can you convert it to a string along the way?

Comment: I don't believe exactly what you are looking for can be done. Though if you can share some more context, maybe there is a workaround using Apps Script.